# Why is the Mayor planning to get a haircut?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer

In BtVS S3E14 "Bad Girls" Mayor Richard Wilkins III becomes invulnerable after performing a ritual to begin the process of readying for his Ascension. After testing his new invulnerability by letting one of Balthazar's vampire minions attack him, he checks off 'Become invincible' on his day's list of tasks.

However, further down the list he has 'Haircut' as a task he is yet to complete - how is he supposed to get a haircut **after** becoming invulnerable?

Note: I'm aware it says invincible here and that *technically* isn't the same as invulnerable, however he does refer to himself as both invulnerable and impervious to harm later in the season.

[image: Checklist of Mayor Richard Wilkins III in BtVS S3E14]

Comment: Hair is dead cells. Hopefully they’re not invincible/invulnerable, else they’ll just pile up forever, causing a gross mess in the world he worked so hard to take over.

Comment: In the [show script](http://buffyangelshow-gallery.com/database/buffy/transcripts/s3/3x14.pdf) the list reads "*He reaches into his coat pocket, takes out a pad and pencil. A "To Do" list. Angle on: The List. Among "Greet Scouts" "Plumber Union reschedule" "Call Temp Agency" the Mayor checks the box next to "become invincible."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a subtle joke. This is Mayor's To Do list. You will notice that it is not numbered. That implies that tasks in the ToDo list can be done in any order. Also, it is possible that doing a task out of order makes another task on the list impossible. In that case, you just cross the task off the list and write "irrelevant now" by the side of it instead of making a [check mark sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_mark) to check it as complete.

You will also notice that he has "Call Temp Agency" and "Meeting with PTA" on it.

PTA is short for Parent Teacher Association.

Where's the joke? He has the same attitude towards such a weird task like "Become Invincible" as to his other more mundane tasks, which would arguably be more in the job description of a mayor. You would think that "Become invincible" is the harder and much more important task. Thus the subversion.

Tv tropes calls that trope "[Bread, Eggs, Milk, Squick](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BreadEggsMilkSquick)"  or maybe its parent "[The last of these is not like the others](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheLastOfTheseIsNotLikeTheOthers)". (warning: tvtropes link!)

Another possibility is that taking a haircut/ cutting your hair is not considered harm which need to be prevented. It is painless and hair is indeed just dead cells. If your cells are dead, do they really need protecting?
Human poop contains some cells. Most of dust in our homes are dead skin cells. Would that brand of invincibility that Mayor found make all of his cells, even dead ones, invincible? How about shaving? Those are also hair follicles. I would guess not.